Redirect Bitnami Wordpress
I migrated my version of Bitnami Wordpress Apache on AWS to a new instance with Wordpress 6.5.4. I loaded the server, configured the Letsencrypt certificate and restored the backup. Okay, the blog works fine.
I use CloudFront, in Origins with a reference of Origin name my-blog to Origin Domain blog.mydomain.com
And my Origin settings are:
blog.mydomain.com
https only,
TLS v1.2,
in Add custom header - optional, I have it configured
header name referer
and value blogMyadmin
My problem now is to make a redirect so that every time I access my blog through the blog.mydomain.com page it is automatically redirected to mydomain.com/blog
I made the configuration in the wordpress-htaccess.conf file, and at first the blog was redirected, but when I try to put it into production, it goes into a loop with a sequence of mydomain.com/blog/blog/blog.... and returning error 404
Any suggestion?
I have already configured the wp-config.php files and also the vhosts file, but at certain times the server does not respond, or I can no longer access wp-admin
